# Java Swing application freezes out

Tags: java, c, swing, out-of-memory

We have a Java application which is kinda huge and requires too much memory, although I set the initial and maximum memory using `Xm` flags, but sometimes it freezes, and we get an `OutOfMemoryError` after 1-2 min (if we're lucky).

We need to restart the application if this happens.

We run the program by a native c application which simply runs a command line.

### Questions

1. What if I don't set the `Xmx` flag?
2. Does it mean unlimited memory usage?
3. How can I realize if the application is frozen in either C or Java?

Comment: Creating a heap dump might help in analysing what is going wrong. 
http://www.fiveminutes.eu/java-heap-dump/ or http://www.jahia.com/community/blogs/tips-and-tricks-for-analyzing-java-virtual-machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What if I don't set the Xmx flag?

Then the JVM defaults to a (typically modest) size of memory for the app.

> Does it mean unlimited memory usage?

No.

> How can I realize if the application is frozen in either C or Java?

Fix the memory leak<sup>1</sup>.

Note that the question I answered used 'release' as opposed to 'realize'.  After careful consideration, I feel the answer should remain exactly the same.  Either 'releasing (memory)' or 'realizing (there is a problem)' is not going to actually *fix* the problem.  It is better either way to *fix the actual problem (a memory leak)*.

---

As an aside.  I don't think the problem is in the C code, but a simple test (launch the app. from the command line) should reveal either way.  The *reason* I think the problem is the Java code is that the `OutOfMemoryError` is detected by a (presumably) fully functional JVM.

If the C app. had **used memory space** that the JVM reserved for itself or the app. I guess the error would be very different, possibly along the lines of: `JVM internal error..`

### 1. Fixing the memory leak

There has been a range of good advice offered by other contributors, that I will revisit here.

- @ChristianKullmann started it off by stressing [the importance of memory profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382852/418556).
- @KlasLindbäck followed it up with some excellent resources linked in a comment.

  - [Java Heap Dump](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/java-heap-dump/). 
    *"One way to find memory leaks is analyzing heap dumps. There are several ways to get a heap dump (not including 3rd party tools).."*
  - [Tips and tricks for analyzing Java virtual machine heap memory dumps](http://www.jahia.com/community/blogs/tips-and-tricks-for-analyzing-java-virtual-machine).
      *"Memory dumps are a very useful feature of the JVM to analyze the contents of the memory at any given time, but their usage requires some experience, and in this post I will share with you some tips and tricks that I’ve learned over the years, so hopefully they will be useful to you too."*
- @mKorbel rounded it out with some typical problems to look for:
   *"search in code if there are `close()` all:

  - JDBC,
  - FileIO,
  - Socket,
  - etc 
    and in finally block, then you'd love re_engeneering too much"*

Comment: Thanks buddy, but we reviewed the code million times to find out the issue, but it happens(2%). With the peak time, app will utilize around 900MB memory, 200MB idle. I also tried to invoke the garbage collector implicit, but didn't help.

Comment: *"..we reviewed the code million times to find out the issue, but it happens(2%)."*  Keep looking.  If you don't know why it happens, that strengthens the case for a memory leak *"I also tried to invoke the garbage collector implicit, but didn't help."*  No, it wouldn't.  The fact that you did not realize it would be pointless underlines that you do not have much experience with this type of problem.  It is well known that the JVM will call GC when it feels it is needed, and if the JVM begins to run out of memory, it **will** be called.

Comment: @parsa porahmad you have to profile the application, search in code if there are close() to all JDBC, FileIO, Socket, etc and in finally block, then you'd love re_engeneering too much

Answer (score 2):

Running your application using C native code does not mean that you may be able to steer the whole memory usage by the JVM parameters.
Try running a memory monitoring for your system (e.g. TOP on Linux with shift+m for memory usage sorting) or better yet profile your application for memory.

Try to get a memory dump after running your application (there are some profiling tools out there, most IDEs provide some feature as well) to check your java objects.

Comment: +1 for 'profiling'..  Trying to solve an out of memory problem in a complex app. without a memory profiler is like trying to fight with one arm tied behind our back.